# How StandardChangeTracker class track a field's change?

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

In Linq if we change a entity's propety value,StandardChangeTracker class will catch the change,how it works?

Answer (score 1):

You can find some information about it [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386982.aspx).